# jvm version for Websphere 6.1.0.23on Solaris

Tags: websphere, solaris, ejb

Hi I'm at big financial institute and we've an application running on Websphere 6.1. on Solaris. Due to MQ Connectivity we had to install fixpack 6.1.0.23. Unfortunately this broke an ejb (1.1) which is still there as legacy (Test missed it).

```
[3/23/10 11:33:18:703 CET] 00000055 EJBContainerI E   WSVR0068E: Attempt to start EnterpriseBean EventRisk_1.0.0#EventRiskEJB.jar#PolicyDataManager failed with exception: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.ibm.ejs.csi.ResRefListImpl.(Lorg/eclipse/jst/j2ee/ejb/EnterpriseBean;Lcom/ibm/ejs/models/base/bindings/ejbbnd/EnterpriseBeanBinding;Lcom/ibm/ejs/models/base/extensions/ejbext/EnterpriseBeanExtension;)V
        at com.ibm.ws.metadata.ejb.EJBMDOrchestrator.finishBMDInit(EJBMDOrchestrator.java:1364)
        at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.EJBContainerImpl.finishDeferredBeanMetaData(EJBContainerImpl.java:4829)
        at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.EJBContainerImpl$3.run(EJBContainerImpl.java:4631)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at com.ibm.ws.security.util.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:125)
        at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.EJBContainerImpl.initializeDeferredEJB(EJBContainerImpl.java:4627)
        at com.ibm.ejs.container.HomeOfHomes.getHome(HomeOfHomes.java:390)
        at com.ibm.ejs.container.HomeOfHomes.internalCreateWrapper(HomeOfHomes.java:938)
        at com.ibm.ejs.container.EJSContainer.createWrapper(EJSContainer.java:4783)
        at com.ibm.ejs.container.WrapperManager.faultOnKey(WrapperManager.java:545)
        at com.ibm.ejs.util.cache.Cache.findAndFault(Cache.java:498)
        at com.ibm.ejs.container.WrapperManager.keyToObject(WrapperManager.java:489)
```

We cannot reproduce the issue on our desktop boxes (it all works fine there) and we do not have direct access to our the Solaris machines (dependent on the deployment department) we do suspect a discrepancy on the jvm but we're not sure.

My question is two fold:

1. can you confirm IBM's [statement](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?rs=180&uid=swg24022256) that fixpack 6.1.0.23 for solaris indeed runs on jvm 1.5.0_17b04 our installation tells us ./java -version java version "1.5.0_13" But deploy department is not eager to investigate.
2. Do you see some other solution, apart from hiring big blue's con$ultancy?

kind regards,
Jeroen.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest open up a PMR and that is the official way to confirm any issue that you may have with respect to the note that you had referenced.

I would take this opportunity to clarify some terminology. 6.1.0.23 is the complete version info and the fixpack is "23" here.

And this note that you had states clearly that "**Java SDK 1.5.0 SR9 Cumulative Fix was fully tested with WebSphere Application Server V6.1.0.23.**". It does states that this CF would result in **"The cumulative fix for Solaris will upgrade to 1.5.0_17-b04"**.

The statements imply that IBM would support this JDK version for WAS 6.1.0.23 that it is supported via the formal support process.

Would this JDK fix the EJB issues for you is another question all-together? The error java.lang.NoSuchMethodError doesn't sound like one which is going to fixed as a result of this JDK Cumulative fix. I haven't looked at the error in detail though.

Caveat: I work for IBM but this opinion is mine and does not in any way reflects that of my employer.

HTH
Manglu